# ArangoDB Java API create database not working in 3.1.RC3

Tags: java, maven, graph-databases, arangodb

I have installed ArangoDB 3.1 RC3 community edition and created maven project with below code

```
ArangoDB arangoDB = new ArangoDB.Builder().host("127.0.0.1").port(8529).build();

    String dbName = "mydb";
    try {
      arangoDB.createDatabase(dbName);
      System.out.println("Database created: " + dbName);
    } catch (ArangoDBException e) {
      System.err.println("Failed to create database: " + dbName + "; " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Here is my pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>mydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>ArangodbTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>ArangodbTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.arangodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>arangodb-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Database is not created in ArangoDB and no exceptions are thrown, its keep on running..

I have tried with arangodb-java-driver 4.0.0 and 4.1.0 as well, but still not working

Help me to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With ArangoDB 3.1-RC1 to 3.1-RC3, you have to start the server with an extra endpoint for VelocyStream communication, e.g.

```
--server.endpoint vpp+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529.
```

The same for ssl:

```
--server.endpoint vpp+ssl://127.0.0.1:8530
```

If you also want to use the web interface, you need an endpoint only with tcp. You can use both endpoints (one with vpp, one without). You only need two differnt ports. Then you can use both the driver and the web inertface, e.g.

```
--server.endpoint vpp+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529 --server.endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:8530
```

With the ArangoDB final version **3.1**, you need the driver in version **4.1.0**, because we changed the velocystream protocol in this version, to remove the need of an extra velocystream endpoint.

Driver version 4.1.0 only works with the final release - which we release at the moment - and not with the RCs. 3.1 should be available in the next 1-2 days.

Answer (score 0):

I think you lost some code. Try this :

> ArangoDB arango = new
>   ArangoDB.Builder().host("127.0.0.1").port(8529).user("root").password("yourpass").build();