# ArangoDB - Executing AQL using java driver 4.0.0 using filter returns null

Tags: arangodb

I am using the Java driver 4.0.0 and DB version 3.1. When I try to query, using FILTER, the ArangoCursor returns with a null element. Tried using Vpack and POJO. Neither of them work.

Comment: I guess u can help me on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355244/arangodb-java-api-create-database-not-working-in-3-1-rc3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the DB in version 3.1.RC2. It is fixed in final version 3.1, which we release at the moment. It should be available in the next 1-2 days. With that version you need the driver in version 4.1.0, because we changed the velocystream protocol in the DB version 3.1, to remove the need of an extra velocystream endpoint. Driver version 4.1.0 only works with the final release and not with the RCs.

Comment: Thank you. will test and confirm